# Wordpress авторизация

Tags: php, база-данных, wordpress, авторизация

Есть сайт на Wordpress. Есть база данных mysql, в ней таблица с логинами/паролями+ещё поля, работающая с программой на компьютере. Как прикрутить эту бд или таблицу к сайту? чтобы при авторизации пользователя, сайт брал логин/пароль из другой бд/таблицы?

Comment: У WP свой принцип кодирования паролей с префиксами и пр. В Вашем случае можно создать пользователей с такими же логинами и обращаться к нужным строкам второй базы по сравнению логинов. Подключить вторую базу в WP можно так: `$wpdb2 = new wpdb( 'user', 'pass', 'name_bd', 'IP-server' );`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте фильтр в `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'filter_auth', 10, 3 );
function filter_auth( $user, $username, $password ){
    // Проверьте имя и пароль по своей базе
    // Если успешно, надо создать объект WP_User и присвоить его переменной $user
    // Если неуспешно, надо создать объект WP_Error и присвоить его переменной $user

    return $user;
}
```